# Django - cannot load image saved to database

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

Exactly as the title says i cannot load the image i saved in the database.

Im am saving the uploaded images in "TV/media/logo_image/"
Thi is my MEDIA_URL:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Tv/media')
```

My model:

```
class EmpresaProfile(models.Model):
    empresa = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, default="")
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logo_image', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.empresa
```

This is my views.py:

```
def index(request):
    empresa = EmpresaProfile.objects.all()

    return render_to_response('Tv/index.html',{'empresa': empresa})
```

template:

```
    <div style="height: 100px;">
    {% for empresa.logo in empresa %}
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ empresa.logo }}" alt="" width="1000px" />
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

This is the vey first page i access so this is mu url:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),]
```

I am getting source "unknown" in the image tag

thank you

Comment: Click `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `i` then tap to `Elements` and find your image and write what the url in attribute `href`. Seems like your media url is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your forloop in template like this

```
<div style="height: 100px;">
    {% for emp in empresa %}
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ emp.logo }}" alt="" width="1000px" />
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it for static files is by using

```
static()
```

For media, you should do something like this:

```
<img src="{{ product_image }}" alt="" />
```

And in the view function for that page:

```
link_to_home_page = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

product_image   = link_to_home_page + one_new_product.main_picture.url
```

Also don't forget for development server, use this:

```
    if settings.DEBUG:
      urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
      urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT + os.path.altsep)
```